# Creating nuget from a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I am trying to create a nuget with the following commands in VS 2013

```
nuget spec
nuget pack Package.nuspec -Prop Configuration=Release
```

My problem is resulting nuget package also contains the NuGet.CommandLine package and this increases the size from 4KB to 1MB. Is there a way to exclude this package?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a NuGet.CommandLine package as a dependency? You can check packages.config or project.json to find out. If for some reason you need it during development, you can mark this dependency as a [developmentDependency](https://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/nuget-2.7). This should prevent it from being packed when your project is packed.